# A very simple CASE statement in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, case

If an entry in column1 is larger than or equal to 0 then it should print 1 in column2. Else it should print a 0.

The table looks like this:

```
create table table1 (column1 REAL);
insert into table1 values (8);
insert into table1 values (-10);
insert into table1 values (53);
```

And this is the query:

```
SELECT column1
CASE 
WHEN column1 >=0 THEN 1
ELSE 0
END as column2
FROM table1;
```

So simple, but not working.  Any help is greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a comma after the column1 column name.

```
SELECT column1,
CASE 
WHEN column1 >=0 THEN 1
ELSE 0
END as column2
FROM table1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Result columns must be separated with a comma:

```
SELECT column1,
       CASE ... END AS column2
FROM table1;
```